# MySQL Calculations using variables

Tags: mysql

Why is this not working? I would like to get the result of:

`(@sum_hours * @rate_hours) + (@sum_travel * @rate_travel) + (@sum_miles * @rate_miles)`

The results of my sub queries are as follows:

`@sum_hours = 5.00000, @sum_travel = 2.00000, @sum_miles = 0.00000`

`@rate_hours = 35.00000, @rate_travel = 35.00000, @rate_miles = NULL`

`@_rate_hours = CAST(IF(@rate_hours, @rate_hours, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)) = 35.00000
@_rate_travel = CAST(IF(@rate_travel, @rate_travel, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)) = 35.00000
@_rate_miles = CAST(IF(@rate_miles, @rate_miles, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)) = 0.00000`

So now that I have some values, I'm doing:

`@total:= (@sum_hours * @_rate_hours)`

I expect this to be 175, but it returns NULL. If I directly declare @sum_hours as 5

`@sum_hours:= 5`

I get 175, as expected. Am I doing something wrong? How can I get this to return 175, assuming I don't know that the values are supposed to be 5, 35 and 175?

@sum_hours is being cast as decimal, but with and without the cast it does not work.

---

Edit:

This is a stripped back version of the query, as the JOINs and subqueries aren't relevant, just the return details. All numeric fields are stored as FLOAT in the database. The values are confirmed in the result, but the calculation for @total does not work (returns null).

I have worked around this using COALESCE and some other bits, but I'm still curious as to why it would not calculate properly - or what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT

  @sum_hours:= CAST(hours AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),
  @sum_travel:= CAST(travel AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),
  @sum_miles:= CAST(miles AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),

  @rate_hours:= (SELECT ... returns 35),
  @rate_travel:= (SELECT ... returns 35),
  @rate_miles:= (SELECT ... returns NULL),

  @_rate_hours = CAST(IF(@rate_hours, @rate_hours, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),
  @_rate_travel = CAST(IF(@rate_travel, @rate_travel, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),
  @_rate_miles = CAST(IF(@rate_miles, @rate_miles, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)),

  @total:= (@sum_hours * @_rate_hours) + (@sum_travel * @_rate_travel) + (@sum_miles * @_rate_miles)

FROM table
WHERE
  id = '...'
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Why are you using MySQL for this?

Comment: how did you declare them, what are their original types?

Comment: can you post the sql code you are using?

Comment: What are the exact error messages you get?

Comment: 1. Using MySQL for this as this is to order a limited result set - showing 20 of 10,000 something records, ordered by total. These are unconfirmed costs, so they aren't stored anywhere. The 35, as a cost, comes from the 'default' cost for that type. I could do this in PHP, but would need to return the entire dataset, then sort through and order but that's messy.

2. Declared as SELECT @ sum_hours:=SUM(t1.col1), @ sum_travel:=SUM(t1.col2), etc... The values are selected fine and print in the result as the values I expect, except the total value / final calculation. The columns are FLOAT types.

Comment: 3. I'll update the OP with some code.

4. No error messages. The result I'm getting is NULL though, as opposed to 175.

I had to add spaces between @ and sum_... as SO thought I was trying to tag users.